# Is it possible to avoid rewriting all of a superclasses constructor parameters in a subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, code-duplication

Say for example I have an abstract class `Animal` with multiple parameters arguments, and I want to create a subclass `Dog` with all of `Animal`'s properties, but with the additional property of `race`. As far as I know the only way of doing this:

```
from abc import ABC

class Animal(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name, id, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.weight = weight

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, id, weight, race) # Only difference is race
        self.race = race
        super().__init__(name, id, weight)
```

Is there a way of doing this that doesn't include duplicating all of `Animal`'s constructor parameters within `Dog`'s constructor? This can get quite tedious when there are a lot of parameters, as well as making the code look repetitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use catch-all arguments, `*args` and `**kwargs`, and pass those on to the parent:

```
class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, race, *args, **kwargs):
        self.race = race
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This does require that you put additional positional arguments at the front:

```
Dog('mongrel', 'Fido', 42, 81)
```

You can still name each argument explicitly when calling, at which point order no longer matters:

```
Dog(name='Fido', id=42, weight=81, race='mongrel')
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that using catch-all parameters would make them optional, making it possible to create a Dog with only "race",  but that would throw an exception when calling the supers __init__, cool.(Will accept in 6 mins)